# Split one not merged cell into 3 cells

Tags: excel, cell

I would like to split one cell into three cells, is this possible? The cell was not merged.

I don't want to add two more columns so I can merge the previous and split for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. You have to add columns, merge the ones you're trying to keep the same, and then you will achieve a three cell 'split' by simply not merging the new columns in that row. Cells are fundamental structures and can't be divided.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot split an un-merged cell. You can use the insert cells command instead. If you don't want other cells to shift just insert whole column/s or row/s

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to splitting the cell value by **`"split one cell into three cells"`** than you can use Excel's [**Text to Columns**](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&es_sm=122&q=excel%20text%20to%20columns&oq=excel%20text%20to%20columns&gs_l=serp.12..0i71l4.0.0.0.42731.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0.r-6wexBMht0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.101214132,d.cWw&biw=1920&bih=955&ech=1&psi=d7fdVbjnFMT_-AGAhreYCw.1440593784558.3&ei=d7fdVbjnFMT_-AGAhreYCw&emsg=NCSR&noj=1) command. But if you are referring to cell itself than it is not possible because you cannot split an unmerged cell.